# ¿Es imprescindible el puntero Node* en este prototipo? node_print (FILE * file, const Node * n)

Tags: c

Antes que nada, decir que es en el lenguaje C.

¿Sería imprescindible el puntero `Node*` en el prototipo de esta función?

```
int node_print (FILE * file, const Node * n);
```

O lo podría poner como `node_print(FILE * file, const Node n);`

Siendo `Node` una estructura.

En la función en la que se llama se crearía una variable `Node *n`, que inicializaría con otra función, y es la que se pasaría como argumento a este `node_print()`.

A mí por ejemplo me parece que no es imprescindible, ya que con la segunda opción puedes pasar el argumento de esta manera: `node_print(file, *n);`

Pero un compañero opina que esto no se podría hacer, que sí es imprescindible.

Espero que entendáis a lo que me refiero.

Answer (score 2):

Pues lo tienes tan fácil como hacer la prueba. El siguiente código implementa ambas modalidades:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    int a;
    int b;
};
typedef struct Node Node;

void print_node(Node *n){
    printf("a: %d\n", n->a);
    printf("b: %d\n", n->b);
}

void print_node2(Node n){
    printf("a: %d\n", n.a);
    printf("b: %d\n", n.b);
}

int main(){
    Node *p;

    p = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    p->a = 20;
    p->b = 15;

    print_node(p);
    print_node2(*p);
    return 0;
}
```

Y si lo ejecutas verás que funciona y ambas imprimen correctamente los datos.

Hay que decir que es más eficiente pasar el puntero, pues pasar la estructura obliga a copiar todos los datos de la misma en la pila. Si la estructura tiene muchos campos en su interior, pasar sólo el puntero será más rápido y ocupará menos espacio en la pila.

Observa también que la sintaxis dentro de la función para acceder a los elementos de la estructura cambia según le pases una estructura o un puntero a la misma.